# CakePHP 3 : specific authorization for admin prefix

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, admin

I'm trying to create some restrictions to a small news/blog.

I made the following `admin` prefix route :

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', ['controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action']);
});
```

My issue is that with this rule `$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display']);` in the `beforeFilter` everybody can access the `/admin/Articles/index` or `/admin/Users/index`action

If I use the `isAuthorized` function like below, it solve the probleme for authenticated users but not for anonymous :

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null)
    {
        // Any registered user can access public functions
        if (empty($this->request->params['prefix'])) {
            return true;
        }

        // Only admins can access admin functions
        if ($this->request->params['prefix'] === 'admin') {
            return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
        }

        // Default deny
        return false;
}
```

Is There any way to restrict all the actions for the `admin` prefix to be accessed only by authenticated users ?

Comment: Tip: [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) has this built-in as single config. A bit cleaner if your app's complexity increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition in your `beforeFilter` callback:

```
public function beforeFilter(/* ... */) {
    if (empty($this->request->params['prefix'])
        || $this->request->params['prefix'] !== 'admin') {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display']) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: `beforeFilter` callback of what controller?

Comment: @aexl The one with the routes you want to allow.

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but then you'd have to whitelist the admin prefix inside *every* controller within the admin folder? Or am I missing something?